# How to remove right bottom pager text from jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter, mvcjqgrid, jqgrid-inlinenav

In jqgrid, I want to remove text appearing on pager i.e. `View 1 - 2 of 2`.

all other things are fine on pager.

My grid/pager is as follow:

```
<table id="GrdList">
</table>
<div id="GrdPager">
</div>
```

for pager:

```
            rowNum: 5,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20],
            pager: '#GrdPager',
```

Can you please guide me how to remove appearing text on right bottom corner i.e. `View 1 -2 of 2` (current page and its records).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `viewrecords: true` option from your jqGrid.

Comment: Another issue is, when there are 6 records (Paging 5). So, first page has 5 records and second page has 1 record now, user has deleted 6th record (from page #2). Then, grid still remains on page #2 and no rows exists on page 2 as its deleted. Can you please guide how to solve that.. i think, it should be move to earlier page (last page).

Comment: Thank you, your earlier solution worked. For another question, raised new one "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010232/in-jqgrid-how-to-handle-when-no-records-exists-on-page-or-grid" please see. Thank You