# In jqgrid, how to handle when no records exists on page or grid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter, mvcjqgrid

In jqgrid, when there are 6 records (Paging 5). 
So, first page has 5 records and second page has 1 record now, user has deleted 6th record (from page #2). 
Then, grid still remains on page #2 and no rows exists on page 2 as its deleted. It does not look good when 5 records on page 1 and no records on page 2 though, page selection appeared on page 2.

Can you please guide how to solve that. i think, it should be move to earlier page (last page).

Also, related issue:
when all 6 records are deleted. then, grid still appear.
Insted of that, there should be some label message to appear as no records exists.
How to achieve this ?

Comment: Do you use "local" `datatype` or not? How you delete the rows (which API)? Do you send any data to the server during deleting? The main difference is that the number of row can be changed *on the server*. So during deleting of records locally one makes *refresh* of data and loads the current number of rows on the server. During the time some other rows could be added or deleted.

Comment: sorry for less details. I do custom delete. On click of "hyper link", call the javascript funciton which makes ajax call to server and delete the record. AFter that, i do referesh the grid using `$("#GrdList").trigger('reloadGrid');` . Please guide how to change the page in case it is deleted. also, no records exists then just show label. I got `emptyrecords` but, it appears when page has no record (though header and pager appear).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reccount` options which provides the number or records *on the current page* of the grid. If the number of records is 0 you can do additional action. For example you can trigger `reloadGrid` with additional `page` option (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3808014/315935))

```js
var $self = $(this), // or $("#gridId")
    p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam"), // get all parameters
    newPage;

if (p.lastpage > 1) { // on the multipage grid
    newPage = p.page; // the current page
    if (p.reccount === 0 && p.page === p.lastpage) {
        // if after deleting there are no rows on the current page
        // which is the last page of the grid
        newPage -= 1; // go to the previous page
    }
    // reload grid to show rows from the page with rows.
    // depend on where you use the code fragment you could
    // need reloading only in case 
    // p.reccount === 0 && p.page === p.lastpage
    setTimeout(function () {
        $self .trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: newPage}]);
    }, 50);
}
```

If you need to display some message text in the grid body you can follow [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EmptyMsgInBody.htm) created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4127666/315935). The demo just shows div with the message text in case of `reccount === 0`.